# How do I undo changing the color of an image in Slick2d?

Tags: java, slick

This code colors the enemy red:

```
enemies.get(i).image.setColor(0,1,0,0,1);
enemies.get(i).image.setColor(1,1,0,0,1);
enemies.get(i).image.setColor(2,1,0,0,1);
enemies.get(i).image.setColor(3,1,0,0,1);
```

if I set it to:
`enemies.get(i).image.setColor(0,0,0,0,1);`
it turns it pure black, and if I set it to
`enemies.get(i).image.setColor(0,0,0,0,0);`
it turns the enemy invisiable

How do I un-color enemy red? as in return to state as it was before it was colored.

[Documentation link](http://www.slick2d.org/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't fiddle with the alpha at all if you're not wanting to change it. Use the [non-alpha version](http://www.slick2d.org/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#setColor%28int,%20float,%20float,%20float%29).

```
enemies.get(i).setCurrentColor(1,0,0);
```

Then create this method:

```
setCurrentColor(int r, int g, int b) {
    image.setColor(0,r,g,b);
    image.setColor(1,r,g,b);
    image.setColor(2,r,g,b);
    image.setColor(3,r,g,b);
}
```

Then when you want to return to no color, just texture, set the enemy to white:

```
enemies.get(i).setCurrentColor(1,1,1);
```

Turns out there's a `setImageColor` function that Eric mentioned in his answer. I checked the source:

```
public void setImageColor(float r, float g, float b) {
    setColor(TOP_LEFT, r, g, b);
    setColor(TOP_RIGHT, r, g, b);
    setColor(BOTTOM_LEFT, r, g, b);
    setColor(BOTTOM_RIGHT, r, g, b);
}
```

So, `setImageColor` is not any different than calling `setColor` on all four corners. Just in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to track the last color set before changing it red, and use that when you want to restore the color.

Comment: but there is no other colors, its just enemy.png image , when he gets hit, it changes red.

Answer (score 1):

An `Image`'s default color is 1,1,1,1 (rgba) a.k.a. *opaque* (or *non-transparent*) *white*. Use `Image.setImageColor` to reset it:

```
enemies.get(i).image.setImageColor(1,1,1,1);
```

Be sure to use this method instead of applying `Image.setColor` to each of the image's four corners.

Comment: it says setImageColor doesnt exist

Comment: @Matthew Right, I corrected the code for your copy-pasting convenience.